# Почему в функции значение присваивается переменной и отображается, а при выходе undefined

Tags: javascript, функции

```
var el = document.getElementById('scroll');
var twoNext = 0
    this.swipedetect(el,  function(swipedir){
        if (!isNaN(swipedir)) {
            twoNext = swipedir
            console.log(twoNext) // значение присвоилось
        }  
    })
console.log(twoNext)// значение undefuned
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: @mymedia тут вопрос не в том, как вернуть, а в том, что обработчик навешивается, но не вызывается

Comment: в `swipedetect` попробуйте использовать анонимную функцию

Comment: @teran правда что ли не вызывается? Судя по коду в вопросе, он вызывается - как минимум, console.log внутрях отрабатывает.

Comment: @PavelMayorov может и вызывается. на момент первого прочтения кода, я увидел тут что к скроллу навешивается обработчик события, сразу после навешивания вывод в лог. поэтому, решил, что возможно вся проблема путанице, когда и какой участок кода выполняется, особенно если учесть, что вывод в лог не имеет никаких отличительных признаков откуда был вызван.